# Revert back from legacy to UEFI boot

Tags: bios, uefi

I have Lenovo G40-30 which came pre-installed with Windows 8. I changed boot mode from UEFI to legacy mode. Now I can't access the bios by pressing any key <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Now the computer starts very fast showing no bootable media found and I cannot access boot options. Is there any way I can revert back to UEFI mode? Also I read somewhere that I will have to remove my HDD since it will be locked. I didn't disable secure boot.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: If the default was UEFI mode then removing the CMOS battery should reset it back to that. Changing to legacy mode shouldn't have sped up booting though, so if you were able to get into the UEFI/BIOS settings earlier it's puzzling why you can't do so now.

Comment: How long did you wait before reinserting the battery? A UEFI bootable USB stick will obviously not work if you've reverted to legacy BIOS mode.

Comment: I've had to leave it out for up to 30mins on certain systems. If there's a CMOS reset jumper that'll be much quicker naturally.

Comment: You can either access the the firmware options through [Windows](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/advanced-startup-options-menu-in-windows-8/) or cause Windows to not boot 3 times in a row and you will get to the same screen.  At which point you can access firmware options.

Comment: I am not able to access anything in my laptop except - No bootable media found black screen

Comment: Hybrid shutdown (log off-hibernate) disables access to the bios, so if you did a hybrid shut down you will have to access the hard drive on another pc and delete the hiberfil.sys file on the root of the drive. It should solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is only for Lenovo G40-30. I went to official website and found my solution. In lenovo G40-30 there is a NOVO button near charging port. By pressing that button I was able to go to directly to Boot menu, and change my boot mode to UEFI mode from legacy mode.

http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/hnt/lenovo_g40_30_g50_30_bsod_solution_20140925.pdf